# Are 20GB packs available without owning a suitable mobile?

Tags: ubuntu-one

I don't have a suitable phone, but I'd like to sync more than 2GB.  Can I somehow buy a 20GB pack?

Answer (score 7):

From Ubuntu-One website. https://one.ubuntu.com/plans/#storage_panel

```
20-Pack of storage ›

Monthly Price: $2.99 (USD)

Yearly Price: $29.99 (USD)
20 GB of personal cloud storage

Add as many 20-Packs as you want
Pay each month or each year
Purchase in USD or EUR
```

No phone is required. Only the music steaming and contact sync requires a phone, and a separate ubuntu-one subscription add-on

Answer (score 1):

You sure can. Check out the FAQ [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuOne/FAQ).